# Java exit when error occured in native library

Tags: java, jvm

I have native lib crated to read from unix socket. When I cannot connect to unix socket, I would like to catch this in java somehow.

In cpp I have:

```
    if (send(fd, input, strlen(input)+1, 0) == -1) {
        //perror("send");
        retText = err("Cannot send to unix socket");
        ok = 0;
    }
    return retText;
```

Now in java I just expect to get retText with error message, but instead, on error jvm closes and prints message:

> java: : Connection refused

In java code I have:

```
    try {
        System.out.println("NATIVE EXECUTING");
        byte[] bytes = exec(socketFile, channelId, jsonCommand);
        System.out.println("NATIVE EXECUTED");
        bytes[bytes.length - 1] = (byte) ' ';
        String ret = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        if (ret.startsWith("ERROR: ")) {
            throw new StoredException("Cannot execute rpc command: " + ret.substring(7));
        }
        return ret;
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION THROWN");
        throw new StoredException("Cannot execute rpc command", ex);
    }
```

The last two lines of program output:

```
NATIVE EXECUTING
java: : Connection refused
root@tst-cln-01:~/ln#
```

Comment: Have you tested the cpp code on its own to make sure that code is functioning as intended? Is it possible the "Connection refused" message is happening in the cpp code?

Comment: Show C++ code. Apparently the error happens before the given `send` call.